# Javascript with IE 11 issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I have a web application written 15-18 years ago, I am working on asp.net web page which is using obsoleted iframe. the below line of code only works in IE8 and getting objects count =1439, the same line ignores by all other browsers and return null.

### Iframe code:

var frame = window.document.all.tooltipFrame;

I resolved this issue by accesing the element and fixed my code behind instead.

Thank you

Comment: [`document.all`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is obsoleted, use `getElementById()` instead.

Comment: I tried   var frame = document.getelementbyId("frametooltip"); that but it's not working.

Comment: @King *I tried that but it's not working*.. any error? A little explaination would help

Comment: Well then maybe you are not trying to access an element with an id, but something else? How about you _tell_ us what you are actually trying to achieve here, hm?

Comment: @torazaburo Actually `document.all` [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/g15y88wt/) in Chrome and FF, and also in IE11?? Definitely something not use though ... @King you've to use the exact `id` of the element, i.e. `tooltipFrame`.

Comment: @tarazoburo I am using the exact tooltipframe that's what my element ID is.

Comment: I have a combobox, I have to get tooltip for each combobox item. attaching handler which execute JS code if that makes sense?

Comment: Maybe you would post some more code, we'd find out, why `gEBI` doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `document.all` is no longer supported:

> [all is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use getElementById. For info, see Compatibility changes.]

Comment: If I use var frame = document.getelementbyID("myframe"); then var body = window.document.frames("myframe").document.body; \\ getting undefined

Comment: Do you have an element with the id "myframe"? Also it needs to be `document.getElementById("myframe");` not `document.getelementbyID("myframe");`.

Comment: Yes, I do have an element called myframe defined in my.aspx , I am using document.getElementById("myframe"); sorry for the confusion. I am not using getelementbyid("myframe");